# Can a property decorator define the type of the decorator property?

Tags: typescript

I have a property decorator that returns a property descriptor. Is there a way to tell the compiler the type of the decorated property **x** via the decorator?

e.g.

```
// returns a readonly string property descriptor
function d(target, key) {
    return {
        get: function() : string {return 'hello'}
    }
}

// would like type of property x to be `string` either inferred
// or taken from decorator getter signature
class A {
    @d()
    x 
}
```

The problem I'm trying to solve is eliminating extra work for the user of the decorator - my decorators define the property (including type) so repeating the type ( `x: string` in this case) is redundant. The real world example are database classes where all properties (hundreds) are decorated. Currently every property has the decorator AND a specfic type annotation. The pain point arose when I enabled `--strictNullChecks` which means hundreds of properties would need `| null` added to the type (because the database allows setting null as a value). Since the decorator  dictates the property type I am hoping to drop the type declaration.

I see TS includes a generic `TypedPropertyDescriptor` declaration but property decorators have to return `void` or `any` else the compiler errors.

Comment: What kind of functionality are the decorators providing? Are they encoding/decoding data to and from the database as well as setting the values?. By the sounds of it, you're going to have an easier time introducing an abstract class that accepts generics rather than attempting to use decorators to get the job done as like I said previously it's very troublesome for the compiler to interpret the output of the decorated property

Comment: the decorators perform api calls transform and get/set values in the database. Using these decorators I am able to expose database records as POJOs for the user (essentially offering ActiveRecord simplicity for consumers of these classes) The inheritance hierarchy is already uncomfortably deep just in representing the database. :\

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think what you're attempting is currently possible in the current version of Typescript. You're attempting to modify the signature of the class `A` by implicitly setting the type of the property x through the decorator, there is no way for the compiler to know what type x should be and no way for the compiler to know that x should have the `get` method.

There's a big thread on GitHub about a very similar issue with class decorators. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881 Perhaps follow that thread if you're interested!

You could approach this differently and supply a generic with constraints to the `A` class; however, I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve so that may not be an option.